# PHP Filtering an array for 1 url

Tags: php, regex, arrays, web-scraping

I made a script that creates an array of urls scraped from a page and I want to filter the array for just 1 certain url. 
The array currently looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => index.jsp
    [1] => feedback.jsp
    [2] => faq.jsp
    [3] => donate.jsp
    [4] => contact.jsp
    [5] => widgetmaker.jsp
    [11] => http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php
    [12] => http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php
    [13] => http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php
    [14] => http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php
    [15] => http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php
)
```

And what I want it to do is grab one of the "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php" links. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to get only fully-qualified (absolute) URLs:

```
$filtered = array_filter($urls, function($url) {
    if (strpos($url, 'http://') === 0) return true;
    return false;
});
```

If you want both `http` and `https` urls:

```
$filtered = array_filter($urls, function($url) {
    if (preg_match('#^https?://#', $url)) return true;
    return false;
});
```

If you only want exact matches:

```
$filtered = array_filter($urls, function($url) {
    if ($url == 'http://full/url/goes/here') return true;
    return false;
});
```

If you only want to get the first one then:

```
$url = $filtered[0];
```

Comment: I want to grab the "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php" link

Answer (score 0):

I think the ideal would refine the script to catch just one link. Do you know the criteria that should be the final URL?

IMHO, ideally, use a [regular expression](http://es.php.net/manual/es/ref.pcre.php) or, if possible, find the specific string with [strpos](http://es.php.net/strpos), which is more efficient.

Comment: I want to grab the "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php" Link but the problem is that the token varies so Im not sure how to use regex for it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you either want to get the url -- if it exists in the array -- or else `NULL`. This PHP code would do that:

```
function get_url_if_present($wanted, $array) {
     return array_keys($array, $wanted) ? $wanted : NULL;
}
```

...where `$wanted` is the url you're searching for in `$array`, and the return value is a string with the found url if it was present in the array, otherwise `NULL`.

You may call this function like this:

```
<?php

function get_url_if_present($wanted, $array) {
     return array_keys($array, $wanted) ? $wanted : NULL;
}

$arr = Array
(
    0 => "index.jsp",
    1 => "feedback.jsp",
    2 => "faq.jsp",
    3 => "donate.jsp",
    4 => "contact.jsp",
    5 => "widgetmaker.jsp",
    11 => "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php",
    12 => "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php",
    13 => "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php",
    14 => "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php",
    15 => "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php"
);

$url_as_string = get_url_if_present("http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation?_mska_tok=tON-3yIN1n5TVrFAXT3Q&_tgt_url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com%2Fxml.php", $arr);
print $url_as_string;

?>
```

Comment: I want to get the wanted url into a string, also the token is not static.

Comment: That would work perfectly if the _mska_tok was static, but I'm afraid its dynamic. How would you do to get it to grab a link that contains "http://www.example.com/myaccount/accountactivation" ?